# How do you code the following Json object?

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to create a Json object like the following:

```
{"name": "Maximum", "children": [
                    {"name": "where", "size": 299},
                    {"name": "xor", "size": 354},
                    {"name": "_", "size": 264}
                    ]
}
```

Which library to use to create the above Json string and how should the code look like?

Comment: You are asking which library when your question is tagged with GSON?

Comment: I tried Gson and somehow doesn't return the required result. So, I thought I shall confirm by adding this tag. Do you thin Gson can create the above string?

Comment: I'm quite sure that it can. A simple way is to define 2 classes, and one class will have String name and a Children[]. And the Children class will have 2 properties String name and int size. I don't know if there is any better way (e.g. List), though.

Comment: This might help: http://www.json.org/java/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) . It has good support for this. Check out this [user guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide).

Your class structure would look like:

```
class Parent{
        String name;
        Children[] children;
//getter and setter
    }
    class Children{
        String name;
        int size;
//getter and setter
    }
```

then in your code:

```
   Parent parent = new Parent();
    //poppulate parent object with required values 
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    gson.toJson(parent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try XStream Json Parser. I have used it .

http://x-stream.github.io/json-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

This is simple javascript.

```
var obj = {"name": "Maximum"};
var children = [];
children.push({"name":"where", "size": 299});
obj["children"] = children;
```

Comment: And the question is Java. Java != Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

With [jettison](http://jettison.codehaus.org/) you could do something like that:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;


public class JSONTest {

  public static void main(final String[] args) throws JSONException {
    final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("name", "Maximum");

    final List<JSONObject> children = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

    final JSONObject child1 = new JSONObject();
    child1.put("name", "where");
    child1.put("size", 299);
    children.add(child1);

    final JSONObject child2 = new JSONObject();
    child2.put("name", "xor");
    child2.put("size", 354);
    children.add(child2);

    final JSONObject child3 = new JSONObject();
    child3.put("name", "_");
    child3.put("size", 264);
    children.add(child3);

    jsonObject.put("children", children);
    System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());

  }

}
```